# ICMP protocol place in network layers

Tags: internet, tcp

I would like to ask you question about Internet Protocol.

On Wikipedia, they have ICMP protocol on the same level of network architecture as IP protocol, but that is wrong, right? ICMP should be on par with TCP, when it uses IP services. Is there any protocol om the same level as IP?

Comment: I tried to make the title better summarize this question, but actually these are two questions. Consider taking the ICMP part into a question of its own?

Comment: Well, I could, but I thought that if someones knowledge is enough to answer one question its enogh to answer second as well, since they are basically the same range....

Comment: Please remember we're not a forum, nor some help desk. Instead, to be a high quality Q&A site we need questions and answers. Good questions have a good title...

Comment: (Alternatively: yes, your first assumption is correct. So you could also remove the MAC part...)

Comment: OK, I edited it to be better Q/A question I hope....

Comment: ICMP Protocol? Is that like an ATM Machine, EMP Pulse and PIN Number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: technically, yes, there can be two devices on different LANs with the same MAC. But there aren't *supposed* to be, because every device is supposed to have a unique MAC. (Anecdotally, I know a guy who says he once spent days troubleshooting a network issue on a campus, only to find out that there were two NICs with the same MAC on the LAN. I've never seen such a thing IRL, but he claims it's a true story.)

Second: from a handout in my CCNA class, I dug this up: "Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) works closely with IP in providing error and control information that helps move data packets through the internetwork."

Answer (score 0):

TCP is concerned with transport functions.  ICMP is not.  ICMP is intended for testing and status checking purposes, which you might need before any TCP sessions can be undertaken.

IPX is an alternate protocol that is not compatible with IP but is in the same place in the stack.

Not every protocol in the TCP/IP stack exactly follows the OSI model; many protocols (such as MPLS) fall "between" layers.